# How can I connect remotely to a WebSphere Server running on localhost?

Tags: java, websphere-7, rad

So I wanted to try to let one person connect to my WebSphere Application Server remotely. I've already opened up a port on my router, but I don't really know what is the port that WebSphere uses. I couldn't really find much on the internet, and WebSphere is a hell of a complex thing to handle.
I've already tested it on https://www.portchecktool.com/ so the port is not blocked by any firewall.

By connecting remotely I mean that I have a java web application up and running and I want this other person that is not inside my house to be able to get into the application and use it.
I'm using RAD IDE just in case it might help out knowing it.

So where can I find the port that my server uses, in order to then configure to forward connections to that port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know RAD, but there are a couple ways to find out looking at WebSphere itself. If you are already in the admin console, you can to go to Servers in the left pane, click on your server's name, look for the ports link on the right column, and expand that. Look for the defaulthost_secure (or plain defaulthost if not using https.) If you don't, find where WebSphere is installed on your filesystem. There is a file `WAS_INSTALL_ROOT/profiles/profileName/logs/AboutThisProfile.txt` that lists some common ports including defaulthost and defaulthost_secure.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That did it for me. I saw all of those ports and I didn't really know which one of them was... Saved my day man. Ws is so complicated to use honestly